# module compiled with swig not found by python

Tags: c++, python, module, swig

I've a problem with SWIG and python. I've a c-class that compiles correctly, but the python script says it can't find the module.

I compile with:

```
swig -c++ -python codes/codes.i
g++ -c -Wall -O4 -fPIC -pedantic codes/*.cc
g++ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -shared codes/codes_wrap.cxx *.o -o _codes.so
```

This gives me a _codes.so file, as I would expect, but then I have this python file:

```
import sys
import codes

(rest of the code omitted)
```

It gives me:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    import codes
ImportError: No module named codes
```

According to http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Introduction.html#Introduction_nn8 this is all I should have to do...
The files are in the same directory, so the path should not be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Rename your _codes.so to _codes.pyd if its a release build. Rename to _codes_d.pyd for debug builds.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used SWIG, it generated two files. In your case it should be codes.py and _codes.so

You should check why codes.py is not present.

Comment: Thats indeed the problem, there is no .py file. But I have no idea why, and googling doesn't seem to help. SWIG gives me one warning that might be relevant: " Warning(312): Nested struct not currently supported (ignored)", but I don't use nested structs (only one struct with ints), and since the .so file is generated, I suspect that is not the problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you are executing these commands from the same place (directory) _codes.so ends up in . and codes.py ends up in ./codes/ , I think.